# Listing members from multiple AD groups with Get-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

I am trying to get lists of users who belong to one of a list of various groups.

Getting one is fine, using

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'groupname1' | Select name

But trying to return a list of users from 2 groups is vexing me. I can't comma or semi-colon separate, &, or OR with this command. I figured I could just

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'groupname1', 'groupname2'

Or similar, but it appears not. I also tried packing the group names into $groups as a string which didn't work.

Does this command just not accept multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

as the documentation shows it only works with one group https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps

you could do it the other way around like this:

```
"groupname1","groupname2" | Get-ADGroupMember
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Not sure how to mark your answer as the solution (new to the site).

Comment: @Sthom88 You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).